# Why do I get an error message at QGIS training manual 3.3?

Tags: qgis, error, training

I have a problem following the QGIS training manual lesson 3.3 ([Ratio Classification](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_classification/classification.html#moderate-fa-ratio-classification)).

You have to add a column to an SQlite layer. The new column is AREA. I followed the instructions and added it as shown, then saved it, and received the following error message (in orange on the screen)

> Commit errors: Could not commit changes to layer land use

Is the manual wrong, or am I doing something wrong?
Can anyone else duplicate what the manual asks?

Answer (score 1):

I too get the same error for this exercise. If you click on the error message banner it will give you more details of the error. For me this gives...

```
Errors: ERROR: 1 new attribute(s) not added  
  Provider errors:
      SQLite error: duplicate column name: AREA
    SQL: ALTER TABLE "landuse" ADD COLUMN "AREA" FLOAT
```

It appears that the supplied "landuse.sqlite" file in the exercise data is in a confused state: if a connection is made to the sqlite database within QGIS(2.6), then the database is examined via menu Database -> DB Manager -> DB Manager then selecting "landuse" within the database, it can be seen that a field called ACCESS already exists. However, if this layer is loaded into QGIS via the "Add Spatialite Table" button, an examination of layer properties->fields or just opening the attribute table will not show the field.

(Starting with a new copy of landuse.sqlite), if a different column name is added "AreaV2", then the hidden "AREA" field suddenly becomes visible and a different error is generated...

```
Errors: SUCCESS: 1 attribute(s) added.
  ERROR: the count of fields is incorrect after addition/removal of fields!
```

Note: this is using data taken from the official download location...
http://qgis.org/downloads/data/training_manual_exercise_data.zip
Perhaps when the database was created the "AREA" field was deleted after testing, but the deletion method only partially worked?

Answer (score 0):

Adding new columns to SpatiaLite databases works. (Just tested adding a column named AREA of type double in 2.4.) If there is a problem, I would assume that it is that you don't have write access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the "duplicate column" error.  The problem was that the landuse data base needed to be upgraded from version 3 to 4 using the command

> spatialite_convert -v 4 -d land_use.db

This requires the spatialite-tools package to be installed.